# Windows can't be installed on GPT partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, gpt

I got a Windows 10 official release ISO file, so I burned it to a USB flash drive, and tried to boot it. I deleted all but one D: partition, which has all my working files so I can't delete it. I then see that Windows can't be installed on a GPT partition. I don't want to remove my D: partition. I'm using a Toshiba C55D-A5381, AMD E1 CPU.

Comment: You normally would get this type of error if you were booting to the disk in legacy mode.

Comment: you mean that i need to change the boot mode to "CSM Boot" or "UEFI Boot"?

i've test them all, when i'm booting from CSM i got the error "windows can't installed on GPT..." when i use UEFI windows doesn't boot at all

Comment: No, that’s exactly what you do not want.

Comment: maybe i've to install windows 8 on my computer than upgrade to win 10?

Comment: If Windows does not boot at all, when you select EFI mode, you need to figure out why that is.  Do you actually mean the installer won't boot? Because Windows, your current installation, should boot.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to burn the ISO to a USB drive or DVD, taking care to first select the ISO by clicking on the CD icon in the `Format options` box.

Rufus will automatically detect that you are burning a Windows ISO. Next, make sure that the partition scheme says "GPT Partition scheme for UEFI computers".

Change any additional settings, then hit the start button. If all goes well, this new  device will be able to successfully install Windows.

[image: A picture of Rufus, with GPT partition scheme underlined.]